# Dealing directly with USPTO

Tags: uspto

I received the First Office Action from my patent attorney but I do not want to use him anymore, how can I deal with USPTO directly and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I deal with USPTO directly?

You can have your attorney file paperwork to withdraw as the attorney or record - then its all you.

> what should I do?

I would recommend finding another registered practitioner - this is very hard to do yourself unless the office action allowed multiple important claims.

Comment: +1. A lot can happen after the First Office Action and having a competent attorney helps tremendously.